# What would I need for receiving information from my Contact page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to figure out the best way to receive information from a Contact page.  I made a form already; I just need a way to send the information to myself, but I have no idea how to do that, as I'm a bit new to Web development.  I am using Angular for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to look into Google's Firebase. They have options such as the Firestore (Database) where you could send data and later fetch it. You could look into it more here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 and a tutorial that may help could be found here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/28/build-crud-app-with-angular-and-firebase

I am relatively new to Angular and needing to use databases/connections to external sources to do forms, and I started picking up Firebase relatively quickly. There are plenty of tutorials around and the stack overflow community is also here if you need help with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need some kind of back end that can talk to the email server. An api, A service, a hosted application. Look into Azure functions. I think you can get a large number of requests for free. You could write a little C# code to send email and from angular you send the data through a service to the function endpoint.

https://cloudops2pm.com/2017/08/10/send-email-through-azure-function-triggered-by-queue/